# Django 2.2 ImportError:

Tags: python, django

Django не импортирует приложения. Ни какие, ни куда... Я понимаю что проглядел что-то очевидное, но уже порядком устал бороться с этой напастью...
При первом запуске пайчарма в терминале ввожу django-admin startproject core, 
далее перехожу в папку с проектом и в ней пишу python manage.py startapp index (django-admin startapp index - тоже пробовал), ну и собственно все... В проекте в urls.py не могу импортировать views из приложения, не могу импортировать модели во вьюху и т.д. Постоянно получаю ImportError.

Пробовал импортировать по всякому, и просто from myapp import index, и myproject.myapp import views ни как не получается... Пайчарм подсвечивает все красным и все.

В core и index init.py - пустые

---

**Settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'index',
]
```

[image: структура проекта]

[image: Скрин Languages & Frameworks]

Comment: И где у вас в каталоге index находится файл index_page.py, который вы пытаетесь импортировать? Вероятно, вам нужно написать `from index.views import index_page`.

Comment: Это хвост от предыдущей попытки, но если Вы обратите внимание на скрин то не получается импортировать сам модуль index не говоря уже о содержимом модуля.

Comment: Т.е. конструкция типа from index.views import index_page тоже не работает...

Comment: Без PyCharm тоже?

Comment: Хм... Не пробовал. Сегодня вечером попробую.

Comment: 1.А там есть вообще index_page? 2.Это у вас какой из urls?  Если это urls проекта, попробуйте `from .index.views import index_page`.

Comment: Итак. Без пайчарма (через cmd) тоже не работает...
@Александр Да, функция index_page есть. Через точку (from .index.views import index_page) тоже не работает. Это urls.py в корне проекта. Я уже начинаю нервничать ((((

Comment: @Uncle_Ragnar `from core.index.views inport *` тоже пробовали?

Comment: Да. Говорит у core нет модуля index

Comment: Сталкивался с такой мистикой в импорте в python2, когда не был подключен `from __future__ import absolute_import`. На всякий случай, у вас не python2 случайно?

Comment: @Uncle_Ragnar, ну хотя бы core видит. Правда, вероятно, не тот. Попробуйте `from .core.index.view import * ` или `from core.core.index.view import *`. Если не поможет, попробуйте пересоздать файл `__init__.py` внутри index

Comment: Так же обратите внимание, чтобы буква `e` в имени папки `index` была латинской. Иначе это мистика какая-то

Comment: В общем. Все перепробовал. Пайчарм даже переустановил и обновил. На данный момент при импорте приложения и функции подчеркиваются красным, но все работает... Если раньше получал импорт эрор, то теперь все норм.... Что это не понятно...

Comment: @Uncle_Ragnar у вас в настройках Pycharm, в File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Django верно указана опция **Django Project root**?

Comment: Хм, не смотрел. Вечером проверю.

Comment: @VladimirGoncharuk Подскажи пожалуйста, а что именно и где искать? Я скрин в вопрос закинул...